# Alternative of $index for serial number in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to show serial number for a table data which is being populated using `ng-repeat`. The code I am having is like this

```
<tr ng-repeat="usageRecord in applicationUsageDataForReport">
  <td style="text-align: center"><span>{{$index+1}}</span></td>
  <td style="padding-left: 5px; max-width: 200px; text-align: center; width:100px;">
    <span>{{usageRecord.ibu}}</span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

which is working fine. The serial numbers are coming as expected. But when I add a condition in `ng-repeat` using `ng-if` the `$index` value is coming for those records only which are satisfying the condition making the serial number in non-sequential order. What is the alternative for this which I can use so that I can get the serial number in correct order(1,2,3..)

Comment: If `ng-show` is an option for you, then consider using this one instead of `ng-if`. Since `ng-show` do not remove the element from the dom the assigned `$index` won't "disappear" .

Comment: @lealceldeiro I can't use `ng-show` here as the data for the table is coming as a JSON from the service and I need to show only those records from the JSON which are satisfying the condition

Comment: Have you tried creating a [filter](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/common-user-interface-patterns/filtering-and-sorting-a-list.html)? That should make the index refer to the filtered list.

Comment: Have you tried setting the Index outside of the if statement  there is a way to set it in the repeat. You can also try `ng-init="SetIndex = $index"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a plnkr which shows how to use the ng-repeat filter method.
[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/tAg49dQQv0JmR5M99sst?p=preview)

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="usageRecord in applicationUsageDataForReport | filter:filterFunction">
  <td style="text-align: center"><span>{{$index+1}}</span></td>
  <td style="padding-left: 5px; max-width: 200px; text-align: center; width:100px;"><span>{{usageRecord.ibu}}</span></td>
</tr>
```

JS:

```
$scope.filterFunction = function(item){
    /* return true if included false if excluded */
    return true;
};
```